# visual studio 2015 the following error occurred attempting to run the project model server process(1.0.3)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Error in Visual Studio 2015 When ASP.Net Core MVC Starter Application(.NetCore) is created i am getting this error i have not get any solution for the same problem help me to fix this error

[Screen shot of the error ][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTYLE.png

This the full error screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have dotnet core 1.0.3 installed which is coming with VS2017. VS2015 does not support the latest release version of core. You will have to either uninstall 1.0.3 and install the preview version or use VS2017.